# Reply to "I'm going to the dentist"

Tags: conversation

Would it be appropriate to reply to someone saying "I'm going to the dentist" with "Good Luck"? I think it's slightly odd...
What would be a natural reply for that?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Is there some context to this? Is this something that someone said to you, or did you hear someone else say this? Does the person saying "good luck" know *why* the other is going to the dentist?

Answer (score 2):

We say "good luck" when we wish someone **success**: *Good luck in your test! Good luck with the conference! Good luck in your efforts!*

If it comes to treatment, a person may need success too. So, if someone says "Good luck" in this situation, it means they wish successful treatment. In [this article](http://%22But%20I%20also%20say%20'Good%20luck'%20or%20'I%20hope%20things%20go%20well%20for%20you%20today'%20to%20patients%20in%20casual%20encounters.%22) about what not to say (and what to say) to people with cancer, you can read the following:

> ...says Martin Raber,
>   M.D., clinical professor in the Department of Gastrointestinal Medical
>   Oncology... "But I also **say** *'Good
>   luck'* or *'I hope things go well for you today'* to patients in casual
>   encounters."

[Here](https://www.wishesmsg.com/surgery-wishes-messages/) you can read about what to say or write to someone before they undergo surgery. Here's one of the wishes:

> Don’t worry! You are in the hand of best professionals. So, there is nothing to be worried. You’ll see that you will recover soon and we all are visiting you there. **Good luck!**

So, yes, we can say "Good luck" to someone who is going to get medical treatment, including dental one.

Answer (score 1):

The natural reply should be something like "Bye" or "Come back soon", depending on who is replying.

> Good luck

This is because of the fact that many children are scared of the dentist, and thus the other person says "Good luck"